# JAX-RS Return Types

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I know that methods in Jersey are not limited to returning a certain type. For example, all the following methods are valid:

```
@GET public javax.ws.rs.core.Response getJaxRsResponse(){};
@GET public String getString(){};
@GET public javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse getServletResponse{};
```

Is there a full list of the different possible return types for a JAX-RS GET method? Could somebody please point me to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return any type! Many framework implementations of JAX-RS include default serializers for `Response`, `String`, `InputStream`, etc. but you can write and register you own [MessageBodyWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) for any type.

Comment: How would I go about registering a MessageBodyWriter in my Resource?